# How to access Camera2 returned Java datatype for camera settings in Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, android-camera2

I am trying to access the various settings of the Camera2 API in Delphi 11.1 and struggle with how to get access to some of the returned values in my Delphi application:

```
function TPlatformCamera.GetCapabilities: string;
var
  LCharacteristics : JCameraCharacteristics;
  Orientation      : Integer;
  Obj              : JObject;
  IntArray         : TJavaArray<integer>;
  i                : Integer;
begin
  LCharacteristics := FCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(FSelectedCamera);
  Obj := LCharacteristics.get(TJCameraCharacteristics.JavaClass.LENS_FACING);
  Orientation := TJInteger.Wrap(Obj).intValue;

  if (Orientation = TJCameraMetadata.JavaClass.LENS_FACING_FRONT) then
    Result := 'Camera: front' + sLineBreak
  else
    Result := 'Camera: back' + sLineBreak;

  Obj := Characteristics.get(TJCameraCharacteristics.JavaClass.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_ANTIBANDING_MODES);
```

The orientation result works, but how to access `Obj`?

- `CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_ANTIBANDING_MODE` returns an `Array of Integer` as it seems (listed as `int[]` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_ANTIBANDING_MODES))
- `CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE` returns a `Range<Integer>` ([see](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE))
- `CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_STEP` returns a `Rational` ([see](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_STEP))

How to convert them to data types usable in Delphi 11.1?

Comment: "How to convert them to data types useable in Delphi 11.1?". You cannot, which is why the Camera 2 support in Kastri uses Java code to manipulate the CameraCharacteristics values. I have a plan to revisit that support within the next week or so

Comment: Thanks for this info. My current ressearch/attempts are based on the sample in Kastri. I didn't see any Java code in there though. But: it would be nice if you could surface those camera settings, I'm especially interested in the ones listed above and in being able to change them. I'm also interessted in getting informed when the preview image changed and like to have the possibility to access that image data. I haven't seen yet where I can do this, but to be honest: that was not my priority yet...

Comment: Unfortunatelly the student I'm helping needs some solution, as he doesn't have unlimited time... :-(

Comment: People helping here don't have unlimited time either. Delegating your/his problems to a community but claiming that _you_ help him is a questionable practice and understanding... Why not introducing the student to _Stack Overflow_?

Comment: The Java parts are here:
https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Java/Camera
Imports for that Java code are here:
https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/blob/master/API/DW.Androidapi.JNI.DWCameraHelpers.pas